# How to simulate undefined in Dart

Tags: dart

In JS, there is undefined and null. Undefined means "no value", null means "value equivalent to emptiness".
In Dart however (and possibly in other languages, I don't know, but right now I'm using Dart), there is no undefined, only null. Therefore it is impossible to make the distinction between a value equivalent to emptiness and the absence of value.

Is there a standard way of simulating this difference in Dart?

Comment: undefined is not "no values" it means unpredictable value or value that cant be guarenteed to ceome everytime. null means "no value" i.e. a reference without any object or memory

Comment: In dart everything is a reference type including int, double etc and their default value is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The `null` value (of type `Null`) is the only built-in value that represents the absence of a value. It does not distinguish on why the value is absent.

It's also (almost) the only type you can combine with another type directly in the type system. With null safety, you'll be able to write `int?` for `int`-or-`Null`.

If you want another marker for absence, you can use (or write) an `Option` type like:

```dart
abstract class Option<T> {
  final T value;
  bool get hasValue => true;
  Option(this.value);
  factory Option.none() => const _OptionNone();
}

class _OptionNone implements Option<Never> {
  const _OptionNone();
  bool get hasValue => false;
  T get value => throw UnsupportedError("None option has no value");
}
```

Then you can represent either value or no value.
(There are existing implementations of such a class, for example [in the quiver package](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.core/Optional-class.html)).